# java static file loading and design pattern

Tags: java

I have a class named `Entity`. it has a `doOperation` method. But this method can be used when some modules loaded. Also system needs to call this method multiple time in the first phase of the program.

```
class Entity{

public void loadModule(){
//load necessary files
}

public void doOperation(){
//this method needs called multiple times
}

}
```

what happen if i set variables and methods static. is that a good design?

What would be the best way?

- loading objects using constructor
- loading objects using loadFile() method.
- usage of design patterns such as singleton

Comment: What?  Why do you feel that setting the variables to be `static` is a good idea?  That means each instance of `Entity` has the same values for whatever fields you need to interact with.

Comment: if i use static method then these objects not eligible for Garbage Collection. So it would dangerous to load large file modules using static. right?

Comment: Only if you want the data to be garbage collected. And then only if you don't clear your strong references to that data.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a very good question. I find that the right solution is different for different situations.  Here are somethings to consider:

- Thread safety and state.  If you have an object (or Class with static fields/methods) whose state changes with subsequent requests then singleton might not work.  The exception here is some sort of shared queue whose state must change, but in that case please be sure to synchronize any writes and reads to the state of the object.  If you are forced to go singleton (or any other shared object) and have some thread safety problems, then consider using ThreadLocal if each thread can have their own instance of that object, or set the problem field to volatile if its state needs to be updated across all threads.
- Testability.  Singletons and static methods are harder to test against.  It can be done but will be harder and might make for more cumbersome test code.  One way around this is to have a way to give the singleton class a mocked object to use instead of its usual self-constructed object instance.  Static methods are even harder to test, requiring specialized testing tools like PowerMockito.
- Passing the same object (or data) around to every method call.  Sometimes when you decide "hey i'm gonna be a smart programmer and avoid singleton/static" you find yourself having to pass around the same objects to various parts of your code.  Different ways to avoid this would be to go singleton or to refactor so that parts of the code that require the same objects hangout together in the same package or class.  Only small chunk of data should leak out of that to other parts of the code... "tight cohesion, loose coupling".
- Dependency injection.  This is a major deciding factor on whether or not to go singleton/static.  Essentially this helps avoid going singleton/static because your objects get their required dependencies handed to them either through a factory class or some sort of dependency injection framework like Spring.
- Initializing or booting up your program.  Essentially all code starts from one static main method.  Either it is your main method or the main method of a framework/java container(like Tomcat).  Either way you need a hook to get your initializing code to start up.  Depending on what the hook it your will know if singleton/static or object creation is possible.  Take a look at how Servelets works.  I think they do a good job at avoiding singleton/static for initializing your code by insantiating your servlet objects for you and calling their init method.
- Reflection and annotation to obtain instances of objects that you might have just made singleton/static in the past.  Many frameworks use reflections and annotations to wire your application together.  It is a great way to avoid singletons/static design.  Again I use Servelets as an example; Servelets use annotation to register your Servelet class with the underlying Servelet container.

Bottom line there is a lot to take into account.  The good news is that a lot of this may be subjective up to the point where you hit a technical snafu.  At which case you can deal with it and refactor.  Experience allows you to detect these snafus and avoid them.  But many times people just argue about this stuff and they bring up technical concerns that may never pop-up in your scenarios.

EDIT:

- How can I forget GC.  Sometimes you need to avoid creating many objects to reduce GC.  In those cases singleton and static fields may help.  There are also other techniques like sharing common state across multiple instantiations of the same type.  On a video game I a worked on this was very important.  But instead of singleton I use object re-use.  This is another technique where instead of creating a new object you re-use an older one by changing it state to the default or init state.  Use this sparingly when speed is an issue... like creating monsters in the middle of battle in a video game.